# Github actions: Add Docker image and services to use Docker in Docker for DevSecOps

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am trying to implement DevSecOps inside a Github actions pipeline. I have managed to do this in Gitlab CI, however I am unsure on how to do the same in Github Actions.

I need to be able to use the image "docker:a.b.c" as a service before the build and security stages.

**Gitlab CI:**

```
image: docker:19.03.12

services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - apk --update add npm

stages:
  - build
  - security

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - node_modules          # Save the node_modules folder so we can use it in the security-test-sca job

security-test-dast:
  stage: security   
  script:
    - echo "Security DAST testing..."
    - docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name juice-shop bkimminich/juice-shop  # Run juice-shop so we have something to test
    - containerip=$(docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.bridge.IPAddress }}" juice-shop)   # Get container IP so we can test it 
    - docker run -t --name dast owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t http://$containerip:3000 || failure=true  #run DAST testing against juice shop container
    - if [[ "$(docker logs dast >& container-logs ; cat container-logs | grep 'WARN-NEW. [1-9]\d*'  | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]]; then echo 'Failing job due to identified failures'; exit 1; else echo "no issues found"; exit 0; fi  # If issues are found, fail job, if no issues are found pass job
```

**Github Actions:**

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions
name: CD/CD (Continuous integration and continuous delivery)

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  job_build:
    name: Build Job
    runs-on: docker-latest
    steps:
      - name: Compiling the code
        run: echo Compiling the code...
      - name: Compile complete
        run: Compile complete.

  job_security_test_dast:
    name: Security testing DAST
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [job_build]
    steps:
      - name: Security DAST testing
        run: echo Security DAST testing...
```

Comment: See [Migrating from GitLab CI/CD to GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/manual-migrations/migrating-from-gitlab-cicd-to-github-actions). Its subsection [Databases and service containers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/manual-migrations/migrating-from-gitlab-cicd-to-github-actions#databases-and-service-containers) is what you're looking for i.e. [`jobs.<job_id>.services`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices).